# Thread contention on JsonConvert calls?

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, json.net

Has anyone come across thread contention issues using JsonConvert in JSON.NET? I've got a large number of threads calling JsonConvert.Deserialize concurrently, and they appear to be blocking each other. VS Profiler is showing me that all my concurrency issues are buried in Newtonsoft.*. Is this a known thing? Is there something I should be doing to make the deserialize calls run in parallel?

I realize any one call is a forward-only op and won't thread itself, but why would independent deserializations contend?

Comment: Do you mean you're seeing incorrect results, or just unexpected slowdowns?

Comment: It gets progressively slower, the more threads i run

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a non-async method like the following:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonValue);
```

It is a blocking call. Consider using the async version as follows:

```
 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString));
 var value = await task;
```

It turns out JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync() isn't truly async as mentioned by Stephen and shown here(http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObjectAsync_1.htm)

Hope this helps.

Happy coding!

cleankoder

Comment: `DeserializeObjectAsync` is a "fake asynchronous" method; it has no async work to do, so it just pushes (synchronous) work onto the thread pool. This will *negatively* impact scalability. For this reason, `DeserializeObjectAsync` has been marked obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Stephen. It turns out I wasn't getting the obsolete warning and now i see its marked obsolete. And this is what I got from their documentation:[ObsoleteAttribute("DeserializeObjectAsync is obsolete. Use the Task.Factory.StartNew method to deserialize JSON asynchronously: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value, settings))")]
public static Task<T> DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(
 string value,
 JsonSerializerSettings settings
)